# Why isn't my slack bot's app home page loading?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have created a slack bot using Bolt, and am trying to create a home page for it.  I have subscribed to the `app_home_opened` event and am publishing the view and getting a successful response, however the home page just spins in slack for a few seconds before saying "This is still a work in progress".  I have another slack app which works fine and I can't figure out what the difference between the two apps could be.

Here's my code:

```
(async () => {
  // Start your app
  await app.start(process.env.PORT || 3020);

  app.event('app_home_opened', async ({ event, context }) => {
    const yourView = {
      "type": "home",
      "blocks": [
        {
          "type": "section",
          "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "This is a mrkdwn section block :ghost: *this is bold*, and ~this is crossed out~, and <https://google.com|this is a link>"
          }
        }
      ]
    };
    const result = await app.client.views.publish({
      token: context.botToken,
      user_id: event.user,
      view: yourView
    });
    console.log(result);
  });

  console.log('⚡️ Bolt app is running!');
})();
```

Here's my app logs:

```
[DEBUG]   ack() begin
[DEBUG]   ack() response sent
[DEBUG]  web-api:WebClient:0 apiCall('views.publish') start
[DEBUG]  web-api:WebClient:0 will perform http request
[DEBUG]  web-api:WebClient:0 http response received
{
ok: true,
view: {
id: '***',
team_id: '***',
app_id: '***',
app_installed_team_id: '***',
bot_id: '***',
type: 'home',
blocks: [ [Object] ],
state: { values: {} },
hash: '1631738063.S4t8Cj2H',
private_metadata: '',
callback_id: '',
root_view_id: '***',
external_id: '',
title: { type: 'plain_text', text: 'View Title', emoji: true },
close: null,
submit: null,
previous_view_id: null,
clear_on_close: false,
notify_on_close: false
},
response_metadata: {
scopes: [
'reactions:read',
'chat:write',
'channels:history',
'commands',
'groups:history',
'users:read',
'channels:read',
'groups:read',
'im:read',
'mpim:read',
'users:read.email'
]
}
}
```

The log message looks successful to me.  If I change the blocks to be invalid syntax for example, I see a real error.  I can't figure out why I would get a successful response, but my app home won't load.  I've tried adding all the scopes to my bot that it lists in the `response_metadata`, but that does nothing.

Any ideas other things that could be going wrong?

Comment: Hi Michael. Strange, have you verified that you're using the correct token corresponding to the correct app and that the app home setting is enabled in your app config UI?

Comment: Finally go back to this and realized it was a token problem!  Swapped out the token with the correct one and it started working as expected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @sandra suggested, this was in fact due to using the wrong token.  I was using an token from a different app.  Everything was working, I guess it was just getting published to the wrong place.